# making a point counter for a dice game in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a dice game point counter where you are awarded points based on how close your guess of what you thought the number was going to be to what the number rolled is. My current code looks like this

```
function continueL(e){
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.letter('L')){
        add(copter);
        var evorod = readInt("What number do you think it's going to be? You are guessing ");
        println("Please click the die to roll a number");
        mouseClickMethod(contin);
    }
}



function contin(e){
        var num = Randomizer.nextInt(1,12);
        println("The number rolled is.... " + num);
        var numText = new Text("The number rolled is...." + num, "20pt Arial");
        numText.setPosition(50, 200);
        numText.setColor(Color.red);
        add(numText);
    if (num == evorod){
        println("Congrats! You Win! Here is 100 points");
    } else {
        if(num == evorod - 1 || num == evorod + 1){
            println("So close! Here is 80 points!");
        } else {
            if(num == evorod - 2 || num == evorod + 2){
                println("Almost got it. Take 60 points!");
            } else {
                if(num == evorod - 3 || num == evorod + 3){
                    println("Nice try. Take 40 points!");
                } else {
                    if(num == evorod - 4 || num == evorod + 4){
                        println("Whoops... maybe next time? Take 20 points");
                    } else {
                        println("Better luck next time.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    remove(copter);
}
```

But it only displays the final else no matter what your guess was vs the number rolled.

edit: evorod is a global variable

Comment: You probably want `if (...) {...} else if (..) {...} else if (...) {...} else {...}` here, not a nested `if` inside each `else`.

Comment: You need to define evorod outside of the function, it's undefined in contin() because it's scope is only  in continueL()

Comment: A little off topic, but use a variable to determine the difference between `num` and `evorod` for example `const diff = Math.abs(num - evorod);` then use a `switch (diff) {` statement instead of the nested ifs, or a continuous if/else if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`evorod` needs global scope, right now it only exists inside the `continueL()` function so will be undefined when you try to use it in `contin()`.  Fix that by declaring it outside the function.

Meanwhile your `if` statements could be simplified to this, instead of a bunch of separate nested conditionals:

```
if (num == evorod) {
  println("Congrats! You Win! Here is 100 points"); // there is no println in javascript, I'll assume you've coded your own equivalent 
} else if (num == evorod - 1 || num == evorod + 1) {
  println("So close! Here is 80 points!");
} else if (num == evorod - 2 || num == evorod + 2) {
  println("Almost got it. Take 60 points!");
} else if (num == evorod - 3 || num == evorod + 3) {
  println("Nice try. Take 40 points!");
} else if (num == evorod - 4 || num == evorod + 4) {
  println("Whoops... maybe next time? Take 20 points");
} else {
  println("Better luck next time.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a switch statement instead. There are 6 possible outcomes per throw. If you guessed less or more than the actual outcome you lose 20 points per digit away from the true outcome.

First of all, let's find how off your prediction was from the roll. We do that by subtracting (excuse my shabby math).

```
int outcome = ...
int guess   = ...
int difference;
if(outcome > guess)
   difference = outcome - guess;
else if(outcome < guess)
  difference = guess - outcome;

switch(difference)
{
   case 0:
   {
     System.out.println("100 Wondred points!");
     break;
   }
   case 1:
   {
     System.out.println("You get 80 hamsters!");
     break;
   }
}
```

And so on it goes, with a difference of 5 being the lowest score because it means you were 5 numbers away from the outcome.